# Android Jetpack compose form with class state management

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a simple class Person, defined as follow

```
data class User(
    val id: String = "",
    val name: String = "",
    val surname: String = "",
  ...
)
```

Then I have a ProfileViewModel class which has two methods
`getUserById()` and `updateUser()`

```
class ProfileViewModel(private val id: String): ViewModel() {

    var user: User = User()

    fun getUserById() { ... } 

    fun updateUser() { ... }
  
}
```

afterwards I have a composable function with a form, that should be able to initialize the user data into the form field, and then update them

```
@Composable
fun ProfileView(profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel() = viewModel()) {
    Column () {
       ...
    }
}
```

I could create some variable into the composable function and then pass them when I perform the userUpdate, but
How can I perform theese operations using the user variable into the profileViewModel class with a clean and structured code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of ways of doing this. Your initial code does not look like it can progress in a good direction. However, consider the following changes:

Avoid the string dependency in the `ViewModel`. The entire class is not dependent on the string. Even if it is, it should not be passed a constructor parameter. Consider using technologies like compose `State` your `ViewModel` and properly encapsulate it.

```kotlin
 class ProfileViewModel(): ViewModel() {

    val user = mutableStateOf<User>(User.dummy()) // initial value 

    fun getUserById(id: String) { /* Fetch user and set user */ } 

    fun updateUser() { /* Send the user object to the domain layer */ }
}
```

You can now load the current values of `user` into your composable function. As the client is changing his details, the information is synced with the `ViewModel`.

When you are comfortable with this, think about how you can encapsulate the mutable state. Mutable objects and variables should not be exposed since other parts of your code can modify it without considering its consequences.

Comment: I have to initialize user from firebase, once i logged in I need the id (String) to get the user. So, how can I avoid the string dependency? According to the documentation I have to always pass id when I navigate from one view to another (using navbar).

Comment: Compose follows the single activity/multiple composables rule. So you can declare a top-level viewModel to use throughout your application, if that is the answer you're looking for. Another option is caching the user data in Room.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some critical pieces of this puzzle.  You need to store the values of each `User` in either a `List<User>` for short-term use or a database for long term use.

I recommend a database, so you have long-term access to your data across the various states your app could go through.  You can learn all about it with [this tutorial on `room`](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0) which is the best way to implement a persistent data structure with a `ViewModel`.

This will allow you to store and later access `User` data.

Comment: I've a firestore database, this is a form to update the user fields, so I have to take the user object from the db by its id

Comment: This is more of a Firestore / Firebase question then.  You should update your tags so you're casting your net in the right pond.